# Stop tomcat 8 from scanning for TLDs

Tags: tomcat8, tld

I have a Lucee web app that is packaged as a WAR.  Long story short, when the app is deployed, the Lucee runtime places some custom TLD files under `WEB-INF/lucee-server/library/tld`.  These TLD files are intended only for Lucee to read - they are not JSP taglib definitions.

Problem is, Tomcat is scanning those TLD files on restart, and cannot validate them because it cannot find the DTD, thus preventing the webapp from starting.

I've already tried adding

```
<context>
    <JarScanner scanClassPath="false"/>
</Context>
```

but that did not seem to help.

How can I disable Tomcat from scanning WEB-INF for tld files?

Comment: As a workaround, I found in the lucee-server.xml file I could change the tld directory, so I placed it under the META-INF directory instead.